# Gradle Multi-Project Builds vs Composing builds

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle, multi-project

I am a bit confused about the differences of these two strategy.

Which is the guideline if I would like to share a java library among different java Apps ?

Regards,
S.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a general guideline exists, but happy to share how we use the two in our company.

We use **multi-project builds** to organize the different parts of our product. For example, we have subprojects for the business logic, the rest api, the webapp, the mobile app, and the user manual.

In contrast, when working with software our product depends on, but isn't *part of* our product, using a **composite build** can be useful. For example, our product's webapp is based on a framework. For official releases of our product, we rely on the official releases of the framework only. However, in development we sometimes want to test a bugfix in the framework that has been applied to the framework's code base but that hasn't been relased yet. A composite build allows us to build the framework from source and run our product against that build.